# scipy interpolate gives varying results

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, radius

I'm trying to get the same answer when reading of an interpolated function in Python using scipy.interpolate.interp1d but when I change the size of the x linspace I get different results.

Below is a simplified case where I feed the interpolated functions different radii and they return drastically different results.  I can't work out why this is happening so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

M_centre = 2e30
G = 1.67e-11
m_test = 6e24
radius = np.linspace(5,1e2,1000)
radius2 = np.linspace(5,1e21,1000)
V_circ = np.sqrt(G*M_centre/radius)
V_circ2 = np.sqrt(G*M_centre/radius2)

velocities_circ = interp1d(radius,V_circ)
test_r = velocities_circ(50)
print(test_r)

velocities_circ2 = interp1d(radius2,V_circ2)
test_r2 = velocities_circ2(50)
print(test_r2)


Out: 
817312853.7629617
2584569596.664017
```

I've thought about maybe the step size of the linspace is causing the varying reading on the interpolated function but it surely can't vary by an order of magnitude can it?

Edit: I have also tried this method using numpy.interp but it gives the same results as above.

Comment: You don't change the number of points, you change the values of `radius`. [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) has the structure start, stop, number of points. Different input, different output. Try `np.linspace(5, 1e2,100)` vs `np.linspace(5, 1e2,10000)`. Same radius, same output.

Comment: True, but given that both linspaces are passed through the same function and both cover a range including where I'm evaluating the interpolation at (ie x=50) then surely they would give the same results? Sorry I've seen your edit..

Changing the linspaces as you wrote above still gives varying results:
817312669.6680217
817312669.668102
albeit smaller in difference

Comment: Actually, it is was pretty stupid, what I wrote. Even changing the number of points changes the output, but not as drastically. `Interp1d` doesn't know the underlying function to generate your point pairs, it just produces a linear interpolation between two adjacent points. Change any of the two points, and you change the linear interpolation curve. In your case, increasing the stop value without changing stepsize moves the points further away from each other. Since your sqrt function is not linear, the interpolation between two points differs.

Comment: Ah okay then, so I guess the added distance will change the result so maybe the only way to get around that problem is to perform a unit conversion such that the max(radius2) = max(radius) and then undo the conversion after reading off the interpolation. Thanks MrT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick illustration of the problem with reduced numbers for contrast:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M_centre = 2e30
G = 1.67e-11
m_test = 6e24

radius1 = np.linspace(5,1e3,10)
radius2 = np.linspace(5,1e2,10)

V_circ1 = np.sqrt(G*M_centre/radius1)
V_circ2 = np.sqrt(G*M_centre/radius2)

velocities_circ1 = interp1d(radius1,V_circ1)
test_r1 = velocities_circ1(50)
print(test_r1)

velocities_circ2 = interp1d(radius2,V_circ2)
test_r2 = velocities_circ2(50)
print(test_r2)

plt.plot(radius1, V_circ1, "ro", label = "radius1")
plt.plot(radius2, V_circ2, "bx", label = "radius2")

plt.plot(radius1, velocities_circ1(radius1), "r")
plt.plot(radius2, velocities_circ2(radius2), "b")
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0, 400)
plt.show()
```

I think the reason for the different output is obvious.
[image]

And the equivalent diagram for same range (5, 1e2), but different number of points (3 vs 10):

[image]